# Call to undefined method DOMDocument::createDocumentType()

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

I have the following script snippet. Originally I did not realize to use getElementById that I needed to include createDocumentType, but now I get the error listed above. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
...
$result = curl_exec($ch); //contains some webpage i am grabbing remotely

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->createDocumentType('html', '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd');
$elements = $dom->loadHTML($result);
$e = $elements->getElementById('1');
...
```

Edit: Additional note, I verified the DOM is correct on the remote page.

Comment: I've never had to use `createDocumentType`. Are you sure `getElementById()` doesn't work without it? Also, id starting with numbers are technically not allowed.

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as `DOMDocument::createDocumentType`. Where did you get the idea there was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMDocument` does not have a method named `createDocumentType`, as you can see in the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). The method belongs to the [DOMImplemetation class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It is used like this (taken from the manual):

```
// Creates an instance of the DOMImplementation class
$imp = new DOMImplementation;

// Creates a DOMDocumentType instance
$dtd = $imp->createDocumentType('graph', '', 'graph.dtd');

// Creates a DOMDocument instance
$dom = $imp->createDocument("", "", $dtd);
```

Since you want to load HTML into the document, you don't need to specify a document type, since it is determined from the imported HTML. You just have to have some `id` attributes, or a DTD that identifies an other attribute as an id. This is part of the HTML file, not the parsing PHP code.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$element = $dom->getElementById('my_id');
```

will do the job.

Comment: Ok originally I was using $dom = new DOMDocument(); followed immediately by getElementById. What I'm not understanding from my searches is how do I specify the id attribute of a webpage I don't control the content? Could you provide an example using my snippet but minus the createDocumentType? In the meantime I will try your way. I was originally getting an error of fatal on getELementById and searches led me to this current solution...

Comment: WOW ok. So that was the original code I had before the screwy version above. I was getting a bunch of errors and warnings though. With your version (my original) the solution was as simple as @$dom->loadHTML($result); to squash the errors.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation to bring me back to square one. :-)